# how do I calulate the days and month in php?

Tags: php

Element: `"added_date" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`, is stored in database like `2019-10-30 21:25:57` I would like to calculate how many days ago since the last post was edited; in my case there is be to 7 days ago.

```
<?php
if ($_POST) {
    extract($_POST);

    $dataupdate = array(
        "email" => $email,
        "contactname" => $contactname,
        "submissions" => $submissions,
        "ispublish" => $ispublish,
        "added_date" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
    );

    $ins = $db->insert($dataupdate, PREFIX . "submissions");

    $_SESSION["add_message"] = 1;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        location.href = "index.php?action=contact_submissions";
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: _Side note:_ Instead of using `extract()` to dynamically create a bunch of variables that you won't have control over (since it comes from userland), just access the values directly with `$_POST['email']` and so on.

Comment: Your question is very unclear at the moment. Calculate days and months how? For what purpose? Please edit the question and include a proper explanation of what you're trying to do. Add some example date, expected result and what you're currently getting.

Comment: I want to calculate the how many days ago since the last entry posted in database.

Comment: i am only getting the date in date base like that (2019-10-30 21:25:57) now i want to calculate the how many days ago since the last post is edit in my case there is be to 7 days ago.

Comment: Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24503880) with all the information so everyone can see it. If it's in comments, people might miss it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTime. https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php
Example from page:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2019-10-30 21:25:57');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2019-11-31 21:25:57');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Comment: it should be 7 days ago and how can your code result  getting the 32 days?

Comment: one month + one day

Comment: @SaqibShaykh As I understand question, it should work in your case. Just try to use it. I run it with date from question and it works.